# how to change color of header in HTML?

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

Here is my HTML and CSS , the `h1` title appears in blue , and not in red , and i don't know why ? and how to fix it ? thanks a lot

```
<!doctype html>

<h1>les planètes du système solaire <h1>
<h1><style type='text/css'>
body{
 color:red;
 background-color: black}
</style><h1>

<img src ='https://(jpeg link ....)'>
<h2>comme nous pouvons le constater<h2>
<h2><style type='text/css'>

body{
 color:blue;
 background-color:black}
</style><h2>
```

Comment: Malformed HTML won't get you anywhere... Read up on HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you shouldn't declare your styling per heading element, but preferably one time only.

You only need to declare a heading element (like `<h1>` or `<h2>`) once and close the tag as well. Here is the updated code where I added a `<style>` block at the top, so it's applicable for all the elements declared in the HTML file.

Please read more [about document and website structure at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Document_and_website_structure).

```html
<!doctype html>
<style type='text/css'>
  body {
    background-color: black
  }
  
  h1 {
    color: red;
  }
  
  h2 {
    color: blue;
  }
</style>
<h1>les planètes du système solaire</h1>

<img src='https://(jpeg link ....)'>
<h2>comme nous pouvons le constater</h2>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
<h1 style="color: red;">My Heading</h1>
```